# Electron portable build not saving content locally

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

**Use case**

I'm building an app that has support for translations. The way I imagined it is that the app will come with English by default and will be sent around to different places. When it arrives in Germany (for example) a user will add German as a translation and then send it to France. The French user will be able to see both the original language (engligh) and German.

**Background**

The app is a React web app wrapped in Electron.

For the use case I implemented the localStorage API to store content changes and switch between different translations.

**Problems**

After building the app as a portable exe and testing it I started noticing  that the content doesn't carry over to a new PC.

It seems like the data is stored on the system or something else is happening (like localStorage gets wiped when moving the portable exe to another machine).

In my view, because I'm using localStorage and Electron bundles the Chromium browser with the web app I was expecting localStorage to be saved within the portable app.

Would love to hear your opinion on this

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localStorage` is not saved to your app's binary files but rather to a file on your account's part of your PC's file system.

On Linux, for example, Electron creates a directory for your app in `~/.config` and stores your `localStorage` data there. I imagine that you might find a directory for your application in `%APPDATA%` (`C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\` or similar) on Windows.

What you could try is to write your data to a file in your app's resources bundle which would be preserved while re-distributing, but that's another question and answer.